# Free Audio Book (m4a) creator for Mac?

Tags: itunes, audio, audiobook, macos

Is there any free and easy to use audiobook creator for Mac?

I need something that could create a `.m4b` audio book from several .mp3 files and eventually audio tracks. Also possibility to create chapters is important.

As far as I know (correct me), just setting the type to audio book for an audio file does not enable all the audiobook features in iTunes.

Do recommend only solutions that are working in Lion, for example the Audiobook Maker doesn't work because it contains some PPC apps inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m sorry; I don’t know any free apps, but I can suggest two paid apps, if that’s any use.

There’s an app called **Audiobook Wizard** that I used a year or so ago, under Snow Leopard, that seemed reasonably fast and easy to use.

However, it’s a paid app ($4.99) offered through the Mac App Store: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audiobook-wizard/id460967298?mt=12. This is apparently Lion compatible and a decent audiobook editor. I haven’t tested this version though.

The developer also offers a free version, which can be downloaded from his site: http://www.audiobookwizard.com/. This only supports Snow Leopard and below, because it has PowerPC components, but you might like to download it to get a feel for the app.

There’s also **Audiobook Builder**. Again, this is a paid app ($5.99) in the Mac App Store: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audiobook-builder/id406226796?mt=12. I haven’t used this before, and I’m not *sure* if it’s Lion compatible. A cursory search of the forums on the developer’s website doesn’t find any problems, so it might be ok. Might be worth trying; not sure.

---

You’re right about `.m4a` and `.m4b` files. This isn’t so much a problem with iTunes, as the file types. `.m4b` files have the capacity to “bookmark” parts of the file that `.m4a` doesn’t. From [the Wikipedia page on MPEG-4 Part 14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14):

> Audio book and podcast files, which also contain metadata including chapter markers, images, and hyperlinks, can use the extension `.m4a`, but more commonly use the `.m4b` extension. An `.m4a` audio file cannot "bookmark" (remember the last listening spot), whereas `.m4b` extension files can.

Comment: I bought Audio Book Builder.